# Importing cassandra table into spark via sparklyr - possible to select only some columns?

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra, cql, sparklyr

I've been working with `sparklyr` to bring large cassandra tables into spark, register these with R and conduct `dplyr` operations on them.

I have been successfully importing cassandra tables with the code that looks like this:

```
# import cassandra table into spark

cass_df <- sparklyr:::spark_data_read_generic(
  sc, "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra", "format", 
  list(keyspace = "cass_keyspace", table = "cass_table")
  ) %>% 
  invoke("load")


# register table in R

cass_tbl <- sparklyr:::spark_partition_register_df(
         sc, cass_df, name = "cass_table", repartition = 0, memory = TRUE)
       )
```

Some of these cassandra tables are pretty large ( > 8.5bn rows) and take a while to import/register, and some lead to memory overruns, even with 6 nodes running a total of 60 cores and 192gb RAM. However, I only typically need a few of the columns from each cassandra database.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to filter the cassandra database on import/registration so that it only imports some columns or so that it is filtered on the primary key (i.e. by passing `SQL` / `CQL` type queries such as `SELECT name FROM cass_table WHERE id = 5`)?
2. Where would such a query go in the above code, and what form does the syntax take?

I have tried adding such a query as an additional option in the options list, i.e.:

```
list(. . . , select = "id")
```

as well as invoking it as a separate pipe before `%>% invoke("load")`, i.e.:

```
invoke("option", "select", "id") %>%

# OR

invoke("option", "query", s"select id from cass_table") %>%
```

But these do not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip eager cache and select columns of interest:

```
session <- spark_session(sc)

# Some columns to select
cols <- list("x", "y", "z")

cass_df <- session %>% 
  invoke("read") %>% 
  invoke("format", "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") %>% 
  invoke("options", as.environment(list(keyspace="test"))) %>% 
  invoke("load") %>% 
  # We use select(col: String, cols* String) so the first column
  # has to be used separately. If you want only one column the third argument
  # has to be an empty list 
  invoke("select", cols[[1]], cols[2:length(cols)]) %>%
  # Standard lazy cache if you need one
  invoke("cache")
```

If you use predicates which can significantly reduce amount of fetched data set `pushdown` option to `"true"` (default) and use `filter` **before** caching.

If you want to pass more complex query you register temporary view and `sql` method:

```
session %>%
  invoke("read") %>% 
  ...
  invoke("load") %>% 
  invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", "some_name")

cass_df <- session %>% 
  invoke("sql", "SELECT id FROM some_name WHERE foo = 'bar'") %>%
  invoke("cache")
```

Comment: Wonderful, this post has helped me so much... I have done something inspired from this but loading just the right columns from a CSV file.

I wanted to add one may want to register `case_df` so it is possible to use dplyr verbs on it (since sparklyr comes with a dplyr backend).

Registration is done with:
`R_cass_df = sdf_register(cass_df, "spark_cass_df")`


Then dplyr verbs can be applied, example:
`library("dplyr"); R_cass_df %>% filter(foo == "bar") %>% select(id)`

Comment: @zero323 How to connect to remote Cassandra using host, username and password?